# How do you get Rydel to give you both the Mach and Acro bikes?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

In Mauville city, Rydel at Rydel's Cycles lets you switch bikes. I've already completed the entire game, but he still only lets me switch bikes.

How do I get him to give me both bikes? I've heard you need to ride the bikes around a lot, but I've been riding them for a while now. If this is true, how many steps do I need to ride them?

Comment: What makes you think you can have both bikes at the same time?  I don't recall that being possible in the originals.

Comment: @Frank there is a spot in Safari zone that is only accessible by having both bikes, I'm assuming there's more spots like that (although I've only seen the one in safari zone)

Answer (score 33):

The two bikes are necessary for getting some items in a variety of areas including the Safari Zone and various Mirage Caves. To get both bikes, you need to advertise Rydel's Bikes to 3 different people throughout the region

- Mach Bike - Show the Mach Bike to a Hex Maniac in the Route 111 Desert:
  [image: Hex Maniac]
- Acro Bike - Show the Acro Bike to a Bird Keeper in the Acro 
  Bike area of Route 119 - Requires Surf & Waterfall:
  [image: Bird Keeper]
- Any Bike - Speak to a Triathlete in Battle Resort

Once you have spoken to all three of these characters, return to Rydel's Cycles in Mauville City and he will give you the other bike, so you now have both bikes at the same time.

From [Pokemon ORAS Bicycles - Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/bikes.shtml)

Comment: I can confirm this answer is correct, I now have both bikes.

Comment: Just as a side-note, it appears I had somehow already talked to Hex Maniac before the battle resort. I've seen it being mentioned online that the battle resort is the prerequisite for the other two characters to show up. I literally unlocked the battle resort 30min ago, and the Hex Maniac wouldn't show up. So I decided to go to the Bird Keeper first, and after that, when I went to swap the bikes in Mauville to try and go to the Hex Maniac one more time, I simply got the second bike and that was it.