# Why can't I access the Mach Bike?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I currently have the Acro bike. I am trying to switch to the Mach bike at the bike shop.

Every time I talk to Rydel he asks to switch bikes then the game says

> ...got the Mach bike exchanged for an Acro bike!

It **thinks** I have the Mach bike and will only give me the Acro, even though I walked in with the Acro bike.

How do I fix this? I used to be able to switch then suddenly it's acting up.

Comment: Do you get that message every time? If you proceed with the game and talk with 3 precise people you unlock the other bike forever, I hope you can get each one with the bike you already have. This would solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if I talked to the guy near the desert. I know I need the Mach bike to do that. I'll try to find the other two people and see if it unlocks.  The same message appears every time I talk to him. It always says I have the Mach bike and exchange it for the acro bike (even tho I have the acro)

Comment: That's strange. Anyway try that and good luck.

Comment: @Robert - It *says* that but do the bikes actually switch out? As in, if you visit your Backpack, is your Bike the Mach or Acro bike after this?

Comment: Perhaps this can help? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193782/how-do-you-get-rydel-to-give-you-both-the-mach-and-acro-bikes

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a really weird glitch. I'd recommend trying each of these steps in turn:

1. **Restart your 3DS device entirely** - Save the game, press the power button and tap 'Power Off'. Then boot it up again.

   - The reason I recommend powering on/off entirely, rather than quitting & restarting the game, is this will completely cut power to the RAM and restart the core 3DS operating system - and not leave anything floating around in memory, which may still be present on a 'Soft Reset'.
2. **Update the Game** - Connect the 3DS to the internet and update the game. If this is a known glitch, it's possible it's been addressed (inadvertently or otherwise) in a later revision of the game.
3. **Try the game in a different 3DS** - Unlikely, but this could be caused by a problem on the 3DS's side. Perhaps some bit refuses to be flipped from 1 to 0 in RAM? Either case, give it a try.
4. **Restart the Game** - If this glitch is still occurring after a hard reset AND on the latest version, you may have to try and restart the game entirely.

   - I've never heard of this glitch occurring anywhere other than this question, and it is most likely a very hard glitch to encounter, especially twice.
5. **Return your copy for a new one** - If it occurs **again**, I'd be returning your cartridge for a new one. If you've reached this step there is probably a defect with your cartridge