# When and where are the Hex Maniac, Bird Keeper and Triathlete supposed to be available?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm trying to unlock the ability to ride both bikes. However when I looked for the Hex Maniac in Route 111, the Bird Keeper in route 120-121 (I don't remember the route) and the Triathlete in the Battle Resort they weren't there.

I know the exact locations where they're *supposed* to be and they are never there. I have gone to them by cycling, walking, running, struggling, etc.

I have beat the league 3+ times. Any suggestion as to how to find these guys?

Comment: Maybe you've already spoken to them? Try and speak to Rydel

Comment: You may have already seen it, but [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/193791/63192) worked perfectly for me when I did it, directly after gaining access to the Battle Resort. I've never been to any of those spots and *not* had the NPCs there.

Comment: Are you sure you've explored the right location? For example, you need the Mach Bike to find the Hex Maniac in desert.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have been to Battle Resort at least once before you can talk to all three of them. For Battle Resort to be available, you need to finish the Delta Episode.

**Any Bike** - Speak to a Triathlete in Battle Resort **(Talking to this NPC will make others spawn)**
[image]

**Mach Bike** - Show the Mach Bike to a Hex Maniac in the Route 111 Desert
[image]

**Acro Bike** - Show the Acro Bike to a Bird Keeper in the Acro Bike area of Route 119 - Requires Surf & Waterfall
[image]

P.S I'm pretty sure you **need to** be riding Mach bike for hex maniac and acro bike for bird keeper to even spawn, otherwise you won't even be able to get to their location anyway. If you have already spoken to any of them, that particular trainer won't be there.

Once you have spoken to all three of these characters, **return to Rydel's Cycles in Mauville City and he will give you the other bike**, so you now have both bikes at the same time. Your second bike will be in your inventory, just like the first one, so make sure to check for it.

[Source](http://www.serebii.net/omegarubyalphasapphire/bikes.shtml)

Comment: I just realized I have written pretty much the same answer before, but maybe it will help, maybe not, I don't know. I'll leave it for now, if this turns out to be unhelpful, I'll delete it.

Comment: That's not the same answer, providing images is always useful.

Comment: I ended up expanding this answer more and it is a bit specialized towards this question, which differs a little from the other question.

Comment: Just as a side-note, it appears I had somehow already talked to Hex Maniac before the battle resort. I've seen it being mentioned online that the battle resort is the prerequisite for the other two characters to show up. I literally unlocked the battle resort 30min ago, and the Hex Maniac wouldn't show up. So I decided to go to the Bird Keeper first, and after that, when I went to swap the bikes in Mauville to try and go to the Hex Maniac one more time, I simply got the second bike and that was it.