# Why can't I swap bikes with Rydel anymore?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I was trying to get both bikes, and I'm almost done, but I can't swap bikes again. Is something terribly wrong, or is it a glitch??

I don't really know what to do. I've tried leaving Mauville, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Which game are you talking about?

Comment: Is it possible that you [already own both bikes](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193782/how-do-you-get-rydel-to-give-you-both-the-mach-and-acro-bikes)?